# Validating input with vue.js - what does v-model.number really mean?

Tags: vue.js

If I have specified that my input field is numeric, with `v-model.number`, what assumptions can I make for validating the numeric input prior to form submission (or rather, posting JSON to the server)? I.e., can I assume that it is always going to be a number at this point, and can therefore concentrate on testing whether it falls within a certain range, say? Or do I still need to test isNan, etc?

Comment: .number modifier on v-model is mostly used with the number input type, what is does is parse string that contains number into the actual number.
You can use it with input type text, if you type number it would detect it and parse it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I checked with the source. Suffixing with `.number` causes the input value (which is a string even for `type="number"`) to be parsed through the following function:

```
/**
 * Convert a input value to a number for persistence.
 * If the conversion fails, return original string.
 */
export function toNumber (val: string): number | string {
  const n = parseFloat(val)
  return isNaN(n) ? val : n
}
```

This means that you must not assume that the result is always a number, but you can assume that it's never NaN.
However this is not explicitly stated in the official docs and thus might be subject to change.
I would suggest going with `type="number"` if possible and otherwise validate as you would usually do.

Comment: It does that stuff exactly, check this http://jsbin.com/hiyifadino/edit?html,js,output